# TinyMCE in React not showing certain buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I have this code for the TinyMCE editor:

```
<Editor
    apiKey='API'
    onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
    value={content}
    onEditorChange={(e) => setContent(editorRef.current.getContent())}
    init={{
        height: 500,
        menubar: true,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image imagetools charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
            'bold italic forecolor backcolor | h1 h2 h3 | link image | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
            'removeformat | help',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    }}
/>
```

But it only displays these buttons:
[image]

Why doesn't the link and image button appear? Is there something configured wrong?

I using TinyMCE 4.3.0 from npm